# Convex optimization and strong duality

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, euler-lagrange-equation

I am dealing with the following problem:

$\Pi = \inf\, \int v(w(x))dF(x)$

$s.t. \int x w(x)dF(x)\ge 1 $

$w(x)\ge0$

where F(x) is a probability distribution with support on $\mathbb{R}$ and $v(\cdot)$ is a strictly convex function.
In economics, this convex optimization problem is known as the principal-agent model.

This problem is typically solved by writing the Lagrangian

$L(\lambda) = \inf_{w(\cdot)\geq0}{ \int v(w(x)) - \lambda( x w(x) - \lambda) dF(x) }$

and solving it state-by-state; i.e., by solving for each x,

$ \inf_{w(x)\geq0}{ v(w(x)) - \lambda x w(x) }$

Obviously, for this approach to be meaningful, it must be the case that strong-duality holds; i.e., $\Pi = \sup_\lambda{ L(\lambda)}$. Otherwise, there is no guarantee that the solution to the dual corresponds to a solution for the primal.

**My question is how to show that strong duality holds.**

As the objective is convex and the constraints are linear, if Slater's inequality is applicable, then strong duality follows immediately, provided that a feasible solution exists. But most of the textbook results on optimization theory that I know of (including those on Slater's inequality) apply to finite dimensional variables, whereas $w(\cdot)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Seems to me you have strict feasibility here. That is: surely you can find a point satisfying $w(x)>0$ and $\int xw(x)dF(x) > 1$? I don't know if that's enough in the infinite dimensional case but it likely is---just need to find a proof.

Comment: Google a paper called "The Slater Conundrum: Duality and Pricing in Infinite Dimensional Optimization"... that might help

Comment: @George Georgiadis can you provide a reference for this problem?

Comment: @mcpca - http://www.dklevine.com/archive/refs41205.pdf - Eq. (4) and (6), assuming that G is convex and U is linear, and making the following transformation: the distribution dF above corresponds to the distribution of $f_a / f$ in the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the infinite dimensional version of the Lagrange multiplier theorem for convex problems with inequality constraints.

From Luenberger, *Optimization by Vector Space Methods*, Chapter 8, Section 3, Theorem 1, we have that for strong duality to hold in the problem
$$
\text{minimize} \ f(x) \\
\text{subject to} \ x \in \Omega, G(x) \leq_P 0
$$

it is sufficient that

1. $f: \Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ is convex, where $\Omega \subset X$ is a convex set in a linear space $X$;
2. $G: \Omega \to Z$, where $Z$ is a normed space, is convex with respect to the convex cone $P \subset Z$;
3. The convex cone $P$ has nonempty interior;
4. (Slater's condition) There exists a point $x_1 \in \Omega$ such that $G(x_1) <_P 0$, i.e., $G(x_1)$ is an interior point of $-P$;
5. The optimal value is finite.

In this case one has
$$
\underset{x \in \Omega}{\inf_{G(x) \leq_P 0}} f(x) = \max_{z^* \geq_{P^*} 0}\inf_{x\in \Omega}{ \left[f(x) + \left<G(x), z^*\right>\right]}
$$

where $z^* \in Z^*$, the dual space of $Z$, and $P^*$ is the positive conjugate cone of $P$. The maximum on the right-hand side is attained by some $z_0^* \geq_{P^*} 0$, and if the minimum on the left-hand side is attained by $x_0 \in \Omega$, $G(x) \leq_P 0$ then
$$
\underset{x \in \Omega}{\inf_{G(x) \leq_P 0}} f(x) = f(x_0) = f(x_0) + \left<G(x_0), z_0^*\right>
$$

If you don't know some of these definitions, they are all in the reference, but I will now specialize to your problem to derive the conditions in your case. Since you mentioned that you've only seen the conditions in the finite-dimensional setting, I thought it would be best to explain where they came from. Note that the condition is essentially the same (in the finite-dimensional case the cone $P$ is typically the nonnegative orthant $\mathbf{R}^n_+$).

To apply these conditions you must formulate the problem in the form above. A first step would be to choose the class of functions the solution will belong to, i.e. the space $X$. It is important to choose $X$ such that the dual of $Z$ is simple to work with, for instance $X =$ the space of continuous functions. I see that you are interpreting $x(t) \geq 0$ not as a constraint per se but as defining the domain $\Omega$ of $f$ (i.e., what Luenberger calls an 'explicit' (set) constraint as opposed to an 'implicit' (e.g. inequality) constraint). If you are considering solutions which are supported on $\mathbf{R}$ (which I understand is the case) this helps because the dual of the space of continuous functions on a noncompact interval will be a complicated space (and if you were to take this to be a constraint it would have to be 'incorporated into' $Z$).

So, if we take $X$ to be the space of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbf{R}$, we define
$$
\Omega = \{ x \in X: x(t) \geq 0 \text{ for all } t \in \mathbf{R}\} \\
Z = \mathbf{R} \\
G(x) = 1 - \int_\mathbf{R}{tx(t)dF(t)} \\
P = \{t \in \mathbf{R}: t \geq 0\}.
$$

The reason I am restricting to bounded functions is to avoid the issue of $G$ not being defined for all $x \in \Omega$ (I am assuming that $\int_\mathbf{R}{|t|dF(t)}$ is finite).

Clearly $P$ has nonempty interior, and Slater's condition is satisfied if there is an everywhere nonnegative bounded continuous function $x$ such that $G(x) < 0$, or
$$
\int_\mathbf{R}{tx(t)dF(t)} > 1.
$$

This is satisfied for instance by a constant function if $\int_\mathbf{R}{tdF(t)} \neq 0$. We also need to assume that the optimal value is finite, this is the case if for instance $v(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$.

The dual of $Z$ is just $Z$, so the corresponding Lagrangian is
$$
L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda G(x) = \int_\mathbf{R}{\left[v(x(t)) + \lambda (1 - tx(t)) \right]dF(t)}.
$$

Since the conjugate of $P$ is $P$ itself, strong duality means that
$$
\underset{x \in \Omega}{\inf_{G(x) \leq 0}} \int_\mathbf{R}{v(x(t))dF(t)} = \max_{\lambda \geq 0}\inf_{x\in \Omega}{ \int_\mathbf{R}{\left[v(x(t)) + \lambda (1 - tx(t)) \right]dF(t)} }.
$$

I guess that by "solving state-by-state" you mean applying some kind of differential condition for the minimization of the Lagrangian w.r.t. $x$. This would require $L$ to be Gateaux differentiable in $x$. Luenberger presents a condition of this sort applicable when $\Omega$ is a convex cone (which it is in your case) and the Gateaux differential of $L$ w.r.t. $x$ is linear. This is Lemma 1 of Section 7, Chapter 8.

If you were to consider a problem where $F$ is supported on a compact interval, then you could take $x(t) \geq 0$ to be an explicit constraint, take $X$ to be the space of continuous functions on that interval with the supremum norm, and $\Omega = X$, $Z = \mathbf{R} \times X$. In this case the minimization of the Lagrangian w.r.t. $x$ would be unconstrained. The Lagrange multiplier in that case would be a pair $(\lambda, x^*)$ where $x^*$ is a function of bounded variation on the interval we are considering.